# switch - multiple variables

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a script which will work assign different IP ranges depending on the choice, currently I've done something like this:

```
# Get DHCP Scope Start - first IP to check - End Last IP to check 
$X = 0
$Y = 0
$Z = 0
$End = 0

$DHCPServer = "DHCP"
$ScopeID = "10.0.0.0"

switch (Read-Host "Choose device to add: 1 PS3,2 PS4,3 PS4Pro,4 XboxOne,") {
    1 {$z = 1 $End = 20}
    2 {$z = 30 $End = 50}
    3 {$z = 100  $End = 255}
    4 {$y = 1 $z = 1 $end = 100}
}
```

But no matter how I type arguments, PowerShell always return the errors like

> Unexpected token $end in expression or statement

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: You need a semicolon to separate your statements if you want them on the same line.  `{$z=1;$end=20}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some semicolons should do the trick. Alternatively, you could use new lines.

```
# Get DHCP Scope Start - first IP to check - End Last IP to check 
$X = 0
$Y = 0
$Z = 0
$End = 0

$DHCPServer = "DHCP"
$ScopeID = "10.0.0.0"

switch (Read-Host "Choose device to add: 1 PS3,2 PS4,3 PS4Pro,4 XboxOne,") {
    1 {$z = 1; $End = 20}
    2 {$z = 30; $End = 50}
    3 {$z = 100;  $End = 255}
    4 {$y = 1; $z = 1; $end = 100}
}
```